# Run an action only when Widget actually instantiated (not just registered)

Tags: widgets

Suppose you have a widget that depends on a metabox being added to, say, your Posts. An easy way to do this is to simply add the `add_meta_boxes` action to your Widget's constructor and off you go. When that widget is registered with `register_widget()` function, your metaboxes are added and off you go.

The *problem* with this approach is that, well, if the user hasn't actually dragged that widget into one of his sidebars, we *still* add the metaboxes. And, if for some reason we register two different versions of this widget (say we extend the widget), then we're uselessly running the function twice.

`wp_register_sidebar_widget` is called when the widget is registered, but that means it runs regardless of whether the widget actually appears in a sidebar or not.

Is there a corresponding action that is run when a widget is actually loaded into a sidebar? So in other words an action that will only run for each widget that is actually added to a sidebar? Or do we have to dig through a list of widgets gotten through `wp_get_sidebars_widgets()`?

Comment: I don't know your full context, but I think showing parts of UI conditionally on something that goes on in entirely different part of admin is very confusing for user.

Comment: @Rarst, a valid point, and one I'll be sure to keep in mind. In this particular case, I think it makes complete sense to tie the metaboxes in the Edit Post page to the presence of the Widget.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still eager to hear of an action that applies to this use case, but here's a more brute-force approach, if nothing else turns up:

```
// within My_Widget class definition
private static $metaboxes_added = false; // to ensure we don't add them more than once

// inside My_Widget class constructor
add_action( 'init', array( $this, 'add_metaboxes' ) );

// later, inside My_Widget class
public function add_metaboxes(){
    global $wp_registered_sidebars;

    if ( is_admin() && ! self::$metaboxes_added ){
        // These are the widgets grouped by sidebar
        $sidebars_widgets = wp_get_sidebars_widgets();

        foreach ( $sidebars_widgets as $sidebar_id => $widgets ) {
            if ( 'wp_inactive_widgets' == $sidebar_id )
                continue;

            if ( isset( $wp_registered_sidebars[ $sidebar_id ] ) ) {
                if ( in_array( $this->id, $widgets ) ){ // $this is our Widget
                    self::$metaboxes_added = true; // In case we instantiate this sucker twice

                    add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', array( $this, 'add_metabox_stuff' ) );

                    break; // No need to go any further
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```